# How to arrange date/time into AM in/out and PM in/out

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am making a payroll system and I bought the B3 tft from zktechnology and would like to arrange the record.

Currently I can pull the data from the biometric with this format:

```
Count   EmpID   InOutMode   Date
1       1       0           8/20/2012 07:49:01
2       1       1           8/20/2012 12:08:21
3       1       0           8/20/2012 12:43:10
4       1       1           8/20/2012 17:56:15
5       2       0           8/20/2012 07:53:11
6       2       1           8/20/2012 12:02:01
7       2       0           8/20/2012 12:39:56
8       2       1           8/20/2012 17:20:43
9       1       0           8/21/2012 08:10:20
10      1       1           8/21/2012 12:01:26
11      1       0           8/21/2012 13:03:11
12      1       1           8/21/2012 17:11:15
13      2       0           8/21/2012 07:48:26
14      2       1           8/21/2012 12:14:58
15      2       0           8/21/2012 12:59:31
16      2       1           8/21/2012 17:20:12
```

InOutMode:

0 = In, 1 = Out

Now, I want to convert the data above like this:

```
EmpID   Date        AM_In       AM_Out      PM_In       PM_Out
1       8/20/2012   07:49:01    12:08:21    12:43:10    17:56:15
2       8/20/2012   07:53:11    12:02:01    12:39:56    17:20:43
1       8/21/2012   08:10:20    12:01:26    13:03:11    17:11:15
2       8/21/2012   07:48:26    12:14:58    12:59:31    17:20:12
```

So I can save it to the database with EmpID, Date, AM_In, AM_Out, PM_In, PM_Out fields.

I saw a similar code here before but I can't remember the URL.

Update:

VB.net code or sql in ms access format is acceptable.

Comment: 2002-2003 format. but i have no problem using the latest version of access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easiest to create two cross tabs and a query to join them to the available dates and employees.

1 AM Crosstab

```
TRANSFORM Min(tm.Date) AS MinOfDate
SELECT Format([Date],"dd/mm/yyyy") AS dt, tm.EmpID
FROM tm
GROUP BY Format([Date],"dd/mm/yyyy"), tm.EmpID
PIVOT tm.InOutMode;
```

2 PM Crosstab

```
TRANSFORM Max(tm.Date) AS MinOfDate
SELECT Format([Date],"dd/mm/yyyy") AS dt, tm.EmpID
FROM tm
GROUP BY Format([Date],"dd/mm/yyyy"), tm.EmpID
PIVOT tm.InOutMode;
```

Where tm is the name of your table.

You can then join these up.

```
SELECT Alldates.dt, 
       Alldates.empid, 
       am.[0] AS [Am In], 
       am.[1] AS [Am Out], 
       pm.[0] AS [Pm In], 
       pm.[1] AS [Pm Out] 
FROM   ((SELECT DISTINCT Format([date], "dd/mm/yyyy") AS dt, 
                        empid 
        FROM   tm) AS Alldates 
        LEFT JOIN am 
               ON ( Alldates.empid = am.empid ) 
                  AND ( Alldates.dt = am.dt )) 
       LEFT JOIN pm 
              ON ( Alldates.empid = pm.empid ) 
                 AND ( Alldates.dt = pm.dt );
```

Comment: this is probably more elegant of a solution than mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that should produce the results that you want in MS Access:

```
select am_in.empid,
    format(am_in.min_in_dt, "MM/DD/YYYY") as [date],
    format(am_in.min_in_dt, "hh:mm:ss") as AM_In,
    format(am_out.min_out_dt, "hh:mm:ss") as AM_Out,
    format(pm_in.max_in_dt, "hh:mm:ss") as PM_In,
    format(pm_out.max_out_dt, "hh:mm:ss") as PM_Out
from
(
    (
        (
           SELECT empid,
              min(dt) as min_in_dt
            FROM yourTable
            where inoutmode = 0
            group by empid
        ) am_in
        inner join
        (
           SELECT empid,
              min(dt) as min_out_dt
            FROM yourTable
            where inoutmode = 1
            group by empid
        ) am_out
            on am_in.empid = am_out.empid
    )
    inner join
    (
       SELECT empid,
          max(dt) as max_in_dt
        FROM yourTable
        where inoutmode = 0
        group by empid
    ) pm_in
        on am_in.empid = pm_in.empid
)
inner join
(
   SELECT empid,
      max(dt) as max_out_dt
    FROM yourTable
    where inoutmode = 1
    group by empid
) pm_out
    on am_in.empid = pm_out.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
select 
    empid,
    dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,DATE),0) as date,
    max(case when sno=1 then convert(varchar(8),DATE,108)) as AM_IN,
    max(case when sno=2 then convert(varchar(8),DATE,108)) as AM_OUT,
    max(case when sno=3 then convert(varchar(8),DATE,108)) as PM_IN,
    max(case when sno=4 then convert(varchar(8),DATE,108)) as PM_OUT
from
(
    select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by Empid) as sno
    from 
        table 
) as t
group by
    empid,dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,DATE),0)
```

Comment: it says "incorrect syntax near ')'". and btw, is this possible also with ms access? 'cause i am currently using ms access database.